# How do I draw moments on hinged gates?

Tags: moments, hydrostatics

Hello I had a quick question regarding moments on hinged gates on submerged curves. Is there a general rule that we follow when we draw moments on hinges, do we draw the hinges in the direction the gate would open if enough force acts on it? Do we draw the moments in the direction the gate is current pushing against water? Please help me, I included an image as an example, where would I draw my moments on this hinge C? If its the former would this be the correct direction of moments?
[image: Correct moments on C or no?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the gate is drawn fully closed, it is understood that the system is in structural equilibrium with the condition $\sum M_C = 0$ is true, so there is no moment to show on the diagram.

If a mechanical device is required to assist the hinge to resist the rotation due to the hydrostatic pressure, then its presence must be indicated on the hinge point "C" with the direction in agreement with its purpose. In this case, the same direction as rotation produced by the force "P".

[image]

On the diagram above, it is understood that the rotational equilibrium is maintained thru $M_P + M_R - M_W = 0$. ($M_P$ & $M_W$ need not shown though.)